# In Emerald Spire, is a room or entire floor an encounter, and when should I give out treasure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design, treasure, encounters

This is my first time as a GM, and our second session played, and I need this answered: how big is an encounter?

I'm doing the emerald spire and I'm trying to figure out: is the entire level an encounter or is it the room? The main reason for asking this is do I give any treasure for killing a room of goblins, or do I distribute the encounter among the entire level? (i.e. 260g for a room or the entire level?)

Answer (score 3):

As defined in the [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Encounter):

> An encounter is a short scene in which the PCs are actively doing something. Examples of encounters include **a combat with a monster**, a social interaction significant to the adventure’s plot, an attempt to disarm a trap, or the discovery of a mystery or clue requiring further investigation.

So, unless the whole level of goblins are rushing the PCs *all at once*, it is one room.

Comment: Note that I can picture a whole dungeon level's worth of goblins rushing a party quite well. And it looks Awesome.

Comment: As someone about to run Emerald Spire for our group, I can see several of the first few encounters being one running combat.  But not the whole first level.